# Initializer list seems to be dependent on the order of variables in a class

Tags: c++, class, g++, llvm-clang, initializer-list

I am new at C++ and this is my first post here. I am trying to understand initializer lists. The problem is that I get more and more confused. I have made a simple program, that is of no use, but I get a warning I don't understand.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{

    private:
        string monkey2 = "";
        string monkey1 = "";
    public:
        Base(string) : monkey2{monkey1}{
            cout << "monkey1 " << monkey1 << endl;
            cout << "monkey2 " << monkey2 << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The warning I get is:

```
field 'monkey' is uninitialized when used here
```

and an arrow pointing on the row directly below `public:`.

The strange thing is if I change the order of the strings from:

```
private:
    string monkey2 = "";
    string monkey1 = "";
public:
```

To:

```
private:
    string monkey1 = "";
    string monkey2 = "";
public:
```

The warning disappears and I don't understand why. I can compile it using g++ but when using my editor vim with YCM and Clang 7.0.0 i get a warning. I have tried to activate as much warnings as i can in g++, but I can not get the same warning. Is my code or. or is it Clang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data member are initialized in the order they are declared. Hence, when you have

```
class Base {
    public:
        Base();

    private:
        string monkey2 = "";
        string monkey1 = "";
};
```

the variable `monkey2` will be initialized *before* `monkey1`, irrespective of what the ctor `Base::Base()` does. This can lead to hard to spot issues, when the initialization of data members depend on each other. Here,

```
Base() : monkey2{monkey1} { /* ... */ }
```

`monkey2` is initialized by `monkey1`, but due to the order of declaration, `monkey1` isn't initialized at this point as `monkey2` gets initialized first. That's why you get the warning, and that's also why the warning is mitigated by declaring `monkey1` first - then, `monkey1` is set to `""` via the in-class initializer and `monkey2` is initialized with the already initialized `monkey1`.

The following (admittedly subjective) guidelines apply to such a scenario:

- If you can avoid initialization dependencies across data members, do so.
- If you have a ctor initializer list, strictly follow the order in which data members are declared (see [C.47](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c47-define-and-initialize-member-variables-in-the-order-of-member-declaration)).
- If there is a sensible default value for a data member, possibly across ctor overloads, use in-class initialization (but then, don't add another initialization instruction as in your `Base::Base(string)` implementation (see [C.48](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c48-prefer-in-class-initializers-to-member-initializers-in-constructors-for-constant-initializers)).